# Ovh and composer

Tags: composer

I have a site that I just put on OVH hosting shared pro and I try to update Drupal 8 but I encounter several problems:

-If I try to update through the interface I can not update because I have a message related to the PHP bug 2038

I'm trying to use composer.

I have some questions :

- Should I install directly composer on my FTP host or on the www folder?
- When I try the command 
  php composer.phar update drupal / core 
  I get the message "*Composer could not find a composer.json file in home / my_id*"
- When I try in the www directory, I have the message
  *"Drupal / core package for update is not installed.
  Loading dials repositories with package information
  Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  Nothing to install or update
  Generating autoload files
  Drupal \ Core \ Composer \ :: Composer preAutoloadDump
  Drupal \ Core \ Composer \ :: Composer ensureHtaccess "*

For information I have well the composer.json file in my www directory.

Could you help me to start please.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't run Composer on your production environment. Definitely use it to build your site but push a complete build artefact to production (including all the vendor folders and such).

Also the command is `composer update drupal/core` (no spaces).